# Windows 7 SP1 wont update error code 800706F7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

This appears to be a common problem and it has been reported on multiple sites and the answer always seems to come down to removing kb3004394

On the laptop in question I checked and the update is not installed

[image: KB 3004394 is not installed]

I have also tried kb/971058 fix of "Automatically reset Windows Update components" that can be found here but that also made no change

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971058

I have tried even renaming `%systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution` and clearing down the windows update log but no luck

`sfc /scannow` also did not fix it either

I have even tried to use `WuInstall` but that also fails this time with a different error

```
WuInstall /download_to "c:\temp\updates_download"


Copying download to c:\temp\updates_download ...
Copying bundle windows6.1-kb3108669-x64 to c:\temp\updates_download ....  OK
 Downloading finished, checking result ...
 Result Code: Failed
Detailed Result: 0x80240022 - WU_E_ALL_UPDATES_FAILED - Operation failed for all the updates.
```

Machine has Kaspersky Internet security installed